# How to get href off child a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code structure and I am having trouble getting to the value of the href

```
<div class="">
  <div class="">
    <div class="">
      <a href=""><img src=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ev.target.getAttribute("href") ev.target.parentNode.getAttribute("href") are not working.

I should mention that the img tag wrapped in the a tag has a hover state on it as well. I want to click on the image, get the href, preventDefault behavior and trigger some other thing.

Comment: What is the event bound to?

Comment: What goes before and after that? Like `whatishere.addEventListener('whatishere', function() {})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't specified any event on `addEventListener`, so I have assumed one like `mouseenter`. I have assumed that the anchor tag `a` is the first anchor tag in your application.

Please find the working demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L4rvb5z7/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="">
    <div class="">
        <div class="">
            <a href="\something">This is a link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
console.log('Href of \'a\' at load = ' + a);

document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].addEventListener('mouseenter', function () { /*event can be any other like 'click', 'mouseout', etc.*/
    console.log('Href of \'a\' on an event = ' + this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I try that it's working.

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click", function(event){
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.target.getAttribute("href");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <a href="http://www.google.com" id="link" onclick="return false">Google</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Example:
https://jsbin.com/mezonedeko/edit?html,js,output

If I misunderstood what you meant, can you give me full code example, what browser are you using, thank you.

Comment: Your first link points to an empty answer. You should post the code in the answer, not just a link to a jsbin.

Comment: Is it possible that because the img wrapped in the a tag has a hover state on it that is what is stopping preventDefault from working?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'this' variable of the event

```js
document.getElementById("attr1").addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  alert(this.getAttribute("href"));
  alert(this.href);
});
```

```html
<div class="">
  <div class="">
    <div class="">
      <a id="attr1" href="hrefContent">Get Href</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did he say it was a `click` event?